# WebStorm: Set simulator id for React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, webstorm

When I run my `React Native` application `WebStorm` starting an `iPhone X` simulator by default. WebStorm's React Native [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/react-native.html) states that:

> If you selected the `Build and launch` checkbox, choose the target
>   platform, `Android` or `iOS`. Depending on your choice, `WebStorm` will run
>   the bundler with `react-native run-ios` or with `react-native run-android.`
>
> Optionally, type the arguments to be passed to React Native, for
>   example, specify the simulator type through the `‑‑simulator` flag:
>   `‑‑simulator="iPhone 4s"`.

I have set my flag to `iPhone Xs Max` as shown below:

[image]

But it is still starting iPhone X:

```
react-native-cli run-ios "‑‑simulator=iPhone Xs Max"
info Found Xcode project MyProject.xcodeproj
info Building using "xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -configuration Debug
    -scheme MyProject 
    -destination id=0299DF16-DD84-40FB-8B37-55FC7EFCE271
    -derivedDataPath build/MyProject"
```

The id `0299DF16-DD84-40FB-8B37-55FC7EFCE271` is id of iPhone X.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem. What was wrong is dashes of flag simulator. When I copied the code from documentation it had short dashes `‑‑simulator`. Correct one should be `--simulator`.